# How is exponent notation related to this example

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I am not sure what is meant by exponent notation and therefore how to answer this question is baffling me.

Rewrite this in exponent notation:

$\sqrt[3]{x^2y(z-X)^5}$

Comment: Example: $\sqrt[7]{x^2y^3}=x^{2/7}y^{3/7}$.  Also, $\sqrt[5]{x/y^2}=x^{1/5}y^{-2/5}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh so it is literally just a case of doing this?

$({x^2y(z-X)^5})^\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: I think they want $x^{2/3}y^{1/3}(z-X)^{5/3}$.  But what you wrote is *technically* right.

Comment: I should simplify further like you did, as a rule, yes?

Comment: The grader makes up the rules! I gave my reading of what is expected. There is a chance your version would be marked wrong. It isn't.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks for your help. They have a similar one which is $\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is that just a case of doing this? $\frac{x-1}{x^\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: A comment: If you wanted to *evaluate* the thing, say for $x=17$, $y=18$, $z=19$, $X=20$, the "simplified" version would involve more work (more key presses on the calculator). What "simplified" means depends on what you need to do with the thing.  Added: Can't quite read your thing, TeX problem. (Used to happen to me a lot.) From what I can read, they may want $x^{1/2}-x^{-1/2}$. Maybe.

Comment: I have amended it now so that maybe you can read it ok?

Comment: If this is a multiple choice question, it should be easy to spot right choice. If not, there are many equivalent expressions in exponent notation: yours, the one I gave earlier, others.

Comment: I see what you mean! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Magpie : instead of $\frac {x-1}{x^{\frac {1}{2}}}$, would you prefer $(x-1)x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ or instead of that $x^{\frac{1}{2}}-x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ or (just to give them something to think about :) $(x^{\frac{1}{4}}-x^{-\frac{1}{4}})(x^{\frac{1}{4}}+x^{-\frac{1}{4}})$ ( they are all the same(please check for yourself, hope I didnt make a mistake).